# Callback Function executing multiple times

Tags: javascript, callback

I am learning call back functions in Javascript and hence trying to execute a function that uses call back function

```js
var allUserDdata = [];

function logStuf(userData) {
 if (typeof(userData) === "string") {
  console.log(userData);
 } else if (typeof(userData) === "object") {
  for (var items in userData) {
   console.log(items, userData[items]);
  }
 }
}

function getInput(options, callback){
 allUserDdata.push(options);
 callback(allUserDdata);
}

getInput("Alex", logStuf);
getInput({ "Name": "Alex", "Place": "Malaysia" }, logStuf);
```

Instead of printing the output as:

```
0 Alex
1 {Name: "Alex", Place: "Malaysia"}
```

Its printing the output as:

```
0 Alex
0 Alex
1 {Name: "Alex", Place: "Malaysia"}
```

May I know why? Also, I am in the beginner's phase of learning Javascript so please ignore if its a stupid question.

Comment: The answer which was accepted as correct answer achieves not the goal of the task. In your question you have different task asked. At second I answered **at first** yor question correctly. It is not fair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time `getInput` is called, you're `push`ing to the `allUserDdata` array, and then the *whole* `allUserData` is piped to `callback`. So if you only want to log the item that `getInput` was called with and not the whole array, call `callback` on the item, not the array:

```js
var allUserDdata =[];

function logStuf(userData){
 if (typeof(userData)==="string"){
  console.log(userData);
 }

 else if (typeof(userData)==="object") {
  for (var items in userData) {
   console.log(items, userData[items]);
  }
 }
}

function getInput(options, callback){
 allUserDdata.push(options);
 callback(options);
}

getInput("Alex", logStuf);
getInput({"Name":"Alex", "Place":"Malaysia"}, logStuf);
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things here. Consider this set of inputs

```
getInput("Alex", logStuf);
getInput({ "Name": "Alex", "Place": "Malaysia" }, logStuf);
```

the output is

```
 0 Alex
    0 Alex
    1 {Name: "Alex", Place: "Malaysia"}
```

this is because the `allUserDdata` is declared outside all the functions , so the array already contain the previous input. When the second input is fed to to it will have total two elements, therefore the  `logStuf` will iterate over two elements.

So you can keep this array inside the `getInput` function.

Secondly `allUserDdata` is an array , to iterate an array never use for..in

```js
//var allUserDdata = [];
function logStuf(userData) {
  if (typeof(userData) === "string") {
    console.log('Here', userData);
  } else if (Array.isArray(userData)) {
    userData.forEach(function(item, index) {
      console.log(index, item)
    })
  }
}

function getInput(options, callback) {
  var allUserDdata = [];
  allUserDdata.push(options);
  callback(allUserDdata);
}

getInput("Alex", logStuf);
getInput({
  "Name": "Alex",
  "Place": "Malaysia"
}, logStuf);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have called `getInput` function twice. Your mistake: you have to set your variable `allUserDdata` to new array in the function `getInput`.

```js
var allUserDdata =[];

function logStuf(userData)
{
    if(typeof(userData)==="string")
    {
        console.log(userData);
    }

    else if(typeof(userData)==="object")
    {
        for(var items in userData)
        {
            console.log(items, userData[items]);
        }
    }
}

function getInput(options, callback)
{
    allUserDdata = []; // the mistake: you have to set it to new array
    allUserDdata.push(options);
    callback(allUserDdata);
}

getInput("Alex", logStuf);
getInput({"Name":"Alex", "Place":"Malaysia"}, logStuf);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have called logStuf function twice

First time it logged 
0 Alex

Second time it logged 
0 Alex
1 {Name: "Alex", Place: "Malaysia"}

May be you can call logstuff at the second time only

```js
var allUserDdata = [];

function logStuf(userData) {
  if (typeof(userData) === "string") {
    console.log(userData);
  } else if (typeof(userData) === "object") {
    for (var items in userData) {
      console.log(items, userData[items]);
    }
  }
}

function getInput(options, callback) {
  allUserDdata.push(options);
  if (callback) {
    callback(allUserDdata);
  }
}

getInput("Alex");
getInput({
  "Name": "Alex",
  "Place": "Malaysia"
}, logStuf);
```